# Inline button that allows you to redirect the user to the chat room

Tags: python, inline, aiogram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncUS9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWMQo.png)
I searched for information on google and asked AI, but could not find the right answer
After clicking on the inline button, a window appears selecting chats, after selecting the bot is added to the chat. How can I do this using aiogram python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

InlineKeyboardButton(text='➕add to chat➕',                                             url='https://t.me/USERNAME_BOT?startgroup=new')